# Session variables not persistent in PHP5/Apache2/Ubuntu12

Tags: php, apache, session, ubuntu, session-variables

I couldn't find this specific problem around. I have a website that uses session variables (in PHP) to know if the visitor is entering the website or not. If he's new, then I redirect him to the detected language. But if he's not new, you let him go wherever he wants to (even the pages in other languages).

The problem is that the variable used to achieve this `($_SESSION["knownvisitor"])` is not persistent. I've tested the same website in other server and it works just fine, so I'm pretty sure it's a sessions config problem. The problematic server is an Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 with Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.10.

The sessions are stored in `/var/lib/php5`, and I can see the files there but they are empty. The session files belong to `www-data` and have the following rights `-rw-------`. The directory, in the other hand, belongs to "root" and has these rights `drwx-wx-wt`.

I tried using `session_write_close()` before redirecting, as recommended in some forums, with no luck. The redirection is like `header('Location: [URL]')`.

Does anyone have a clue? Thank you!

EDIT: I'll add the code of the script so you can understand it's basic behaviour. This is what I put in the beginning of all the files in my web:

```
function detectedlang($availlangs)
{
 // FUNCTION STUFF HERE TO FIND OUT WHICH IS THE LANGUAGE OF THE VISITOR
 return $detectedlang;
}

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["knownvisitor"]))
{
 $detectedlang = detectedlang(array("en", "es"));
 $_SESSION["knownvisitor"] = true;
 header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/".$detectedlang);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A session only lives for as long as defined in `session.gc_maxlifetime` I think 20 minutes is the default

If you want to check for a returning visitor you'll need to set a cookie

Comment: Hi and thank you! What I'm checking with my script is: is the current pageview of the visitor the first one? If it is, I set the session varibale. When he hits the second page (following a link) the session varibale is there and I know this isn't the first page he visits in a row (or in a session). I'm not interested in knowing if he later returns too the website.

Comment: ok, I don't really know then what the problem might be, I assume you call `session_start()` since you said it worked on a different server

Comment: Yes Andrew, I did, and the script is working on other server. I guess the issue has something to do with PHP storing sessions, but I can figure out how to solve this. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

check `session.save_handler : files` 
Also use `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Yes, thank you. Error reporting said that the index "knownvisitor" was not found on the array. The "save_handler" was correctly set to "files".

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved thanks to the good people of serverfault.com. The problem is that the folder `/var/lib/php5` is owned by root and can't be read by anyone else (`drwx-wx-wt`). This is why PHP (user `www-data`) can't access and retrieve the session data from the file there.

A simple change in groups and permissions got it running:

```
chgrp www-data /var/lib/php5
chmod g+rwx /var/lib/php5
```

In other words, change the group of the directory to `www-data` and allow its members to read the contents.